# No tenant id data in BotFramework Request

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework

I am working on a bot, using the bot framework and microsoft graph API to pull some data.  When trying to get a token for the graph API, I need to pull the tenant id from the turnContext to generate the token (as this is a multi-tenanted application).  However, I'm getting the following error for certain

`Failed to acquire token for client credentials. (AADSTS50059: No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials.`

Here's the code I use to grab the tenant id from the turn context, is there something I'm missing here?

```cs
var tenantId = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.TenantId;
try
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tenantId))
    {
        var teamConversationData = turnContext.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>();
        tenantId = teamConversationData.Tenant?.Id ?? turnContext.Activity.Conversation.TenantId;
    }
}
catch
{
    tenantId = turnContext.Activity.Conversation.TenantId;
}

var accessToken = await _authHelper.GetAppAccessToken(tenantId);
```

When tracing the call, I can see that the tenant id is definitely in the TeamsChannelData, so I'm confused as to why this would fail.  Any help would be appreciated.